# How to prevent circular references in these Django models?

Tags: python, django, circular-reference

Suppose I have 2 Django applications in my project: appA, appB.

appA contains ModelA as follows in its models.py:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=False, blank=False,)
```

appB contains ModelB as follows in its modesl.py:

```
from appA.models import modelA

class ModelB(models.Model):
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=False, blank=False,)
    model_A = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, related_name="blahblah")
```

Now I would like to add an `@property` function to ModelA that will return all instances of ModelB that have this ModelA as their foreign key:

```
@property
def matching_model_bs(self):
    return ModelB.objects.filter(model_A=self)
```

But to do this, I have to import appB.models into appA.models, but that would cause a circular import.
So how can I achieve this without running into circular imports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need for that property. The functionality is already built in: you can just do `mymodelA.modelb_set.all()`.

(Actually, since you've set related_name here, it would be `mymodelA.blahblah.all()`.)

See the docs on [following relations backward](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects).